# SQL HASHBYTES returns different value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

In my Application, the HASHBYTES SQL function returns different values for same string. 
Below is my user creation code.

```
Guid fillerG = Guid.NewGuid(); 
 using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt) VALUES ('" + userNameTxt.Text + "', HASHBYTES ( 'SHA1', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), '" + userPassword.Text +          fillerG.ToString() + "') ),  '" + fillerG.ToString() + "'; ", con))
{
     com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I compare the above inserted row in my Login Page, It doesn't match.
This is my comparing script.

```
SqlCommand loginCom = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(UserID) FROM App_Users WHERE UserName = '" + Login1.UserName + "' AND PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA1', '" + Login1.Password + "' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), PasswordSalt))", loginCon);
```

The first code stores the passwordHash as this:

```
0xDAC9280F85B40C06314228876717E342432807DB
```

But in the query window, the HASHBYTES function with same value returns this:

```
 0xA561FBD35713F922AD761594658C193F12B82791
```

**UPDATE:**
Check this Image, The password Hash stored by the code is different than the password generated by the query (the password I gave is 'ee')

[image: Query Output]

Comment: hashbytes is a deterministic function. If you feed it the same input using the same hash function, you'll get the same result. The only conclusion is that the two strings are NOT in fact equal. I'd print both strings, check for leading/trailing, white space, invisible characters and encoding.

Answer (score 5):

> You are passing Two different String to HASHBYTES thats why you are
>   getting the different Result.

IN This Query:

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt) VALUES ('" + userNameTxt.Text + "', HASHBYTES ( 'SHA1', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), '" + userPassword.Text +          fillerG.ToString() + "') ),  '" + fillerG.ToString() + "'; ", con))
{
     com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You are using `userPassword.Text +fillerG.ToString()` as  String
But

IN This Query:

```
Login1.Password.Replace("'", "''") + "' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), PasswordSalt))", loginCon);
```

You are replacing the quotes

```
Login1.Password.Replace("'", "''")
```

Try like This: use parameterized Query

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO App_Users (UserName, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt) VALUES (@username, HASHBYTES ( 'SHA1', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),@pass')),@salt), con)

    cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@username",userNameTxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@pass",userPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@salt",fillerG.ToString());
```

And

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(UserID) FROM App_Users WHERE UserName = @username AND PasswordHash = HASHBYTES ( 'SHA1', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),@salt)))), con)

cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@username",userNameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@salt",Login1.Password);
```

> Login1.Password and fillerG.ToString() must be Same

Comment: No,,, thats not the issue,,, I am replacing quotes on both codes... 
To make it concise in my post, I removed those in first code.

Comment: I tried adding parameters, but still... :(
Hi, Can you  check the update on my question please.

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem with data type conversion. 
NVARCHAR, and VARCHAR gives me different results.

Comment: Omg I cannot believe its working... 
Its working when I change the datatype of fillerG from UniqueIdentifier to NVarchar in table :) 
Thanks so much friend